# Regex lookahead non capturing with if/then

Tags: json, regex, perl

I have some broken JSON files that I want to fix.
The issue is that one of the fields, AcquisitionDateTime, is malformed:

```
{
    "AcquisitionDateTime": 2016-04-28T17:09:39.515625,
}
```

What I want to do is wrap the value within parentheses. I can do that easily with a regex:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\"AcqDateTime\": (.*),/\"AcqDateTime\": \"\1\",/g' t.json
```

Now, I want to extend the regex so that, in case a JSON is not broken, the content doesn't get wrapped twice in "". The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to mix the lookahead, the if/then statements and the capturing groups. Here's my attempt:

```
Lookahead, if you find a ", then capture what is between it. Else capture everything.
perl -pi -e 's/\"AcqDateTime\": (?(?=\")\"(.*)\"|(.*)),/\"AcqDateTime:\" \"\1\",/g' t.json
```

This is the part I'm interested in correcting:

```
Lookahead for a \"  -> if yes, then capture without it. \"(.*)\" Else capture all (.*)
(?(?=\")\"(.*)\"|(.*)),
```

Would somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: That `\1` should be `$1`. And no need to escape all those `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good start to match the time stamp would be

```
\S+
```

But that also matches the comma, so we switch to

```
 [^\s,]+
```

Now, you want to avoid matching quotes too.

```
 [^\s",]+
```

That's all you need.

```
perl -i -pe's/"AcqDateTime":\s*+\K([^\s",]+)/"$1"/g' t.json
```

Comment: Why not only use `[^"]+` ?

Comment: @Master DJon, My answer already explains step by step how I obtained what I used. What you suggest will match the comma, so it definitely won't work. You could maybe remove the `\s`, although there could theoretically be spaces before the comma that shouldn't be included in the double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The below regex includes a check on partial wrapping of quotes (i.e. only at the beginning or the end of the value), missing wrapping on both ends, or empty value:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\"AcqDateTime\": (|(?<!\")[^\"].*|.*[^\"](?!\")),/\"AcqDateTime\": \"\1\",/g' t.json
```

where `(|(?<!\")[^\"].*|.*[^\"](?!\"))` includes:

- an empty string value, as in the case of `{ "AcquisitionDateTime": }` or
- `(?<!\")[^\"].*`: a value that doesn't start with a quote, as in `{ "AcquisitionDateTime": 2016" }`, or
- `.*[^\"](?!\")`: a value that doesn't end with a quote, as in `{ "AcquisitionDateTime": "2016 }`.